# Motivating results about the category of (simple) graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, topos-theory

My background is in group theory and algebraic geometry. I am due to give an introduction to the topos of graphs to some graph theorists. I understand the material, but what I am missing is some sort of motivating example, i.e. some statement that can be *proven* using category theory (I'm also fine with type theory or whatever), but that can be *understood* using only graph theory.

To be clear, I am not necessarily looking for a result that can *only* be proven using category theory. Saying "hey, you know this result from your field? Here's an alternative proof" would do just fine as a motivation.

Bonus points if the proof is low-level enough that I can actually include it in my presentation and/or if the result is well-known and/or actually useful.

I am grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: You could show that *graphs are the backbone of categories*; ie *every category is formed from the free paths category on a graph /with/ additional identifications*. This is like how every monoid is made from free words, lists, with additional identifications. See https://alhassy.github.io/PathCat

Comment: As a side note, if you're working in a topos of graphs, you're not talking about simple graphs. The topos of functors to sets from the diagram category $\bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet$ is the category of *directed* graphs allowing multiple edges and loops.

Comment: @KevinArlin True, that's why I put the (simple) in parentheses. I don't actually care *which* category of graphs my example uses.

Comment: @BettaGeorge Ah, got it.

Comment: This may not be quite what you're looking for, but [Joyal's proof of Cayley's formula](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2019/12/a_visual_telling_of_joyals_pro.html) is a beautiful category-theoretic proof of a graph-theoretic statement.

Comment: This is also known as a [quiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_%28mathematics%29). Maybe you can search using this keyword. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Quiv) and [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver) and maybe the references in the end.